# Visual Studio Code + MSTEST?

Tags: mstest, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Is there a way to run and debug MSTest V2 from Visual Studio Code?  I'm stumped.

It runs great from the command line: `dotnet test` produces expected results.

Here's what my current launch.json looks like:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Test (Serialization)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/Fact.Extensions.Serialization.Tests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0.1/Fact.Extensions.Serialization.Tests.dll",
        "args": ["test", "-debug"],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/Fact.Extensions.Serialization.Tests",
        "externalConsole": false,
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    }
```

Presumably coreclr launch equates to a `dotnet run`, which would be problematic.

Comment: Take a look at [xUnit](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html) instead.

Comment: xUnit is nifty, however I'm still curious if MSTest is a viable option.

Comment: might be helpful: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensions/testing-extensions ?