# Debugging MSTest Unittests in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-code, mstest

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code to Debug a MSTest unit test project. But the tests just run and the breakpoint is never reached.

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Test (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe",
            "args": ["test"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I debug a unit test (MSTest)? This same problem exists for XUnit.

Comment: For reference [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626407/visual-studio-code-mstest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626407/visual-studio-code-mstest)

Comment: To give context, is there a reason why you must use Visual Studio Code for debugging unit tests?

Comment: @JasonEvans, since we work in a mixed team, Windows, Mac OS and Linux, what other option is there?

Comment: xUnit is not an option for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/diagnose.md#debug-test-platform-components (assumes you're using dotnet-cli tools 1.0.0)

```
> set VSTEST_HOST_DEBUG=1
> dotnet test
# Process will wait for attach
# Set breakpoint in vscode
# Use the NETCore attach config from vscode and pick the dotnet process
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are using the latest version of VS Code (I'm using v1.29.0), debugging unit test is in-built feature.

[image]

You need to first build the solution **`dotnet build`** for the test run & debug options to appear.

Comment: I'm running 1.29.1 and I don't see these options.

Comment: First build your solution `dotnet build` and check?

Comment: How do you run all the test in a project file (Test project) using this method?

Comment: I didn't see the options until I added the tests project to my solution file and did `>Restart Omnisharp` in the command pallette.

Answer (score 0):

Try and reload VS Code, worked for me.
Press Ctrl+Shift+P which opens the command palette and then :

> Reload Window

Answer (score -1):

Before building, remember to include in your .csproj file

`<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>`

or else it will not know what to run...

```
Program.cs(160,21): error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point. [/Users/.../Fraction.csproj]
```