# Debug NUnit dotnet test run from VS Debugger, not Test Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, nunit-console, dotnet-test

**TL;DR** Is there an equivalent `dotnet test` switch to NUnit's `--inprocess`?

Because running `dotnet`  `test` as `StartProgram` with the normal VS Debuigging experience (F5) does *not* allow to debug the test.

---

Our tests are written in NUnit 3.
We are currently migrating our project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6.

Since running tests via `nunit3-console.exe` does not always work (e.g. https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/1253) we are also migrating the runner to `dotnet test` which currently works more seamlessly for us.

**However**, our devs used to be free to debug their tests how they wanted. Some used the VS Test Explorer, others used the normal VS debugger and "F5" with startup settings approx. `nunit3-console.exe --inprocess some.test.dll`.

The problem now is that I cannot find any way to debug an NUnit test started with `<StartProgram>dotnet test` from within the VS GUI.

I found: [How to debug dotnet test in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290166/how-to-debug-dotnet-test-in-vs-code) which suggests setting `VSTEST_HOST_DEBUG=1`, but (a) you cannot set env vars with csproj `StartProgram` and (b) it doesn't seem to work with NUnit anyway.

I want to:

- Set a breakpoint in my NUnit 3 test code
- Run all the tests as a "regular" program from the Visual Studio debugger "F5"
- break into the program on my breakpoints

I could do this with `nunit-console.exe --inprocess` -- is this possible with `dotnet test` at all?

Comment: The title asks one thing, the question another, and even mentions something I've never seen or at least tried - running a single test in a class with multiple test methods using `F5`. All VS versions allow debugging individual tests by right clicking inside the  method name selecting `Debug Tests` or shortcuts like `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T`. The same commands work at the class lever. You can debug all tests with `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+A`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I tried to clarify a bit. Both your mentioned "Debug Tests" as well as "CTRL+R,T" are Test Explorer Commands. I sometimes don't want to use test explorer, but just use the regular debugger on a test console run.

Comment: Unfortunately, even if `dotnet test` runs in-process, it will spawn a `testhost.exe` to run your tests. Setting `VSTEST_HOST_DEBUG` simply tells `testhost.exe` to wait for a debugger to be *manually* connected.

Comment: @NPras - so one could go the route NUnit offered with the [`--debug`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Command-Line.html) switch and start the runner with CTRL+F5 and then manually attach. At which point of course the Test Explorer looks more appealing :-)

Comment: Pretty much yes. Other than the awkward shortcuts, I don't really have anything bad to say about the Test Explorer.

Comment: @NPras - thanks. Aside: We'd prefer for each dev to decide for themselves what they like better. Personally, I find the Test Explorer rather sluggish because it loads 1000s of tests in our sln, but I'm interested in only a few of them.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately MS has always been very opinionated on things. PS, turning off "discover tests in real time" in settings _may_ help with performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allegedly, this is not possible with `dotnet test`:

> Unfortunately, even if `dotnet test` runs in-process, it will spawn a
> `testhost.exe` to run your tests. Setting `VSTEST_HOST_DEBUG` simply tells
> `testhost.exe` to wait for a debugger to be manually connected. - [NPras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77824390/debug-nunit-dotnet-test-run-from-vs-debugger-not-test-explorer?noredirect=1#comment137208258_77824390)

So the situation is similar to what NUnit (console runner) offers/offered with the `--debug` switch.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people